# Server Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Three Questions

**1.The Putty Problem**

I have a running rails application that starts as soon as i start the application via putty ( script/server) but as soon as i close the system or say putty the server too stops and the application is not available to other's.Basically i am new to ruby on rails and i am unable to sort out a solution how to solve this problem.

**2. Speed Problem**

As i have deployed my application , the rendering time of the application seems very high.A page is loaded after many seconds of waiting ( usually > 30 seconds).I have installed Apache server for the application.Could it be that Apache is the bottleneck ? Should i install some other Server for my application ?

**3.Synchronisation Problem**

I work on my application on the localhost.Each time i make changes i got to individually Upload the changes to their respective folder's and that's quite hectic.Could you people suggest any good software or even method that would help synchronise the changes fast ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your program is a child process of the ssh session - if you close the session you also close all children. To prevent this, use nohup (google it for tons of examples) or screen or similar programs that allow you to detatch a process from the current session.
2. If your server isn't extremely slow, apache shouldn't use this much time. Can't say much about it whithout seeing your code and server configuration, but I think this is more likely to be a coding, configuration or maybe database problem than an apache problem. But you could just try it with another webserver and see if it is significantly faster - if yes, your apache configuration is most likely at fault.
3. **Use a versioning system!** Programs like git (which I would recommend) or svn can automate the synchronization process for you, and are useful for a ton of other stuff too.

Comment: Do you mean github by saying git ?

Comment: No, I mean git: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29 - github is just a public (or private if you pay for it) repository server for git.